# How to define methods in composition API?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

With Vue 3 composition API and script setup, I've seen two ways for defining methods within a component:

1. using arrow functions `const increment = () => {}`
2. Using the regular function syntax `function increment()`

Which way is correct?

Comment: Have you tried either way yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ways are ok, the major difference is how `this` and `arguments` are handled, and how they behave as a constructor. Syntax and clarity also play a role in choosing between the two. But apart from that, you can use the two of them as you want to. There is no better ways of doing it.

Arrow functions do not have their own `this`. They capture the value of `this` from the context in which they are defined. This means that this in an arrow function refers to the `this` surrounding the function, and it is not possible to change its `this` using `bind`, `call`, or `apply`. They do not have their own arguments `object`. You will need to use the rest of the parameters (...args) to access the arguments.

Regular functions have their own this, which is determined by how they are called.
They have their own arguments `object` which contains the arguments passed to the function.

[Difference between arrow and regular functions](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/regular-vs-arrow-functions-javascript/#:%7E:text=Regular%20functions%20have%20their%20own,the%20arrow%20function%20was%20created.)